# The linq expression could not be translated on datetime subtraction

Tags: c#, oracle, linq, datetime, entity-framework-core

I'm using ef core with Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore. I've been having an error when the query run

> The LINQ expression 'xy' could not be translated.

Additional information:

> Translation of method 'System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.AddMilliseconds' failed".

model:

```
public class Session
{
    public virtual Datetime STARTED_AT { get; set; }
    public virtual int TIMEOUT { get; set; }
}
```

query:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

var timeoutList = sessionRepository.Table.Include(m => m.Definition)
    .Where(x => DbFunctions.DiffMilliseconds(x.STARTED_AT, now).Value > x.TIMEOUT)
```

How can I rephase the query?

Comment: So, what is the question? Exceptions is clear - not supported. Rephrase your question add details which column types do you have, what they store, show model class and explain what do you expect to see.

Comment: Note that the LINQ expression must be translated to SQL and there is obviously no translation for this function with the Oracle DB provider.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the milliseconds difference between dates in memory.

```
using System.Linq;

var timeoutList = sessionRepository.Table
    .Include(m => m.Definition)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(x => (now - x.STARTED_AT).TotalMilliseconds > x.TIMEOUT)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. With this way, I have to get all records in memory. I'm looking for a resolution from database side.

Answer (score 0):

If your are using a recent version of ef core, you should not import the System.Data.Entity namespace, where one could formerly find the DbFunctions class.

For this query, DbFunctions is not needed, since you can rephrase it in the following way.

```
var timeoutList = sessionRepository.Table.Include(m => m.Definition)
    .Where(x => X.STARTED_AT.AddMilliseconds(x.TIMEOUT) < now);
```